# Use of IRI in RDF N-Triples

Tags: rdf, rdflib, n-triples, iri

I am trying to convert a csv file into RDF N-triples using RDFLib in python. It seems that subject must be an IRI/blank node and also Predicate must be an IRI. For example,

```
<http://example.org/show/218> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "That Seventies Show" .
```

I have only static string literal data in csv file and I don't have any IRI. For example,
`subject: "Name" predicate: "Id" Object="Location"`.

updated the csv format as below,

| Name | Id | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jon | 34 | Texas |
| Michael | 42 | California |

So, is it possible to use only string literal for subject and predicate ? or How to build the IRI for my data?

Comment: no, you have to create IRIs - I mean, how difficult is it to just declare any namespace for your data and use it in combination with the values. I also don't get the format of your CSV. Usually, the header of the CSV makes the schema of the ontology. The other rows make the RDF triples then.

Comment: I have updated the csv format. So, do you mean I can use any general IRI as namespace? I don't have any generalized URI for my data.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct when you state that you *must* have a URI as the subject. This is a major feature of the technology that allows you to link data together.

You *also* need to have a namespace for the predicates. This is another feature of the technology that you won't be able to get around.

If you want the name as the subject I would do something like...

```
subject = rdflib.URIRef('http://ex.com/name')
predicate = rdflib.URIRef('http://ex.com/hasID')
object = rdflib.Literal(id)
graph.add((subject, predicate, object))
```

where `name` and `id` are coming from your CSV.

You might want to add an `rdfs:label` to the node for parsing/readability. A better option in my opinion is to create a new relation, `ex:hasName` and relate the name to the node that way.

#### tldr

Use an existing URI scheme (file://, http://, uuid:, etc) and append something to the end that makes the most sense.

Comment: Thanks. As I don't have any specific URI scheme for my data, can I use generalized one like http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/<data>

Comment: Sure that would work-but if you're sharing the data with anyone they might be confused. `file://data.csv#Jon`, `file://data.csv#Michael` might not be a terrible convention.